# Como crear trigger de update y delete en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

tengo una consulta, deseo crear dos triggers uno de update y delete.

Ya tengo el trigger de insert y funciona perfecto, hace la replica de una a otra tabla con la misma estructura.

lo que busco ahora es que cuando un registro sea actualizado tambien lo replique en la otra tabla, y lo mismo con delete.

Tengo esto:

```
create trigger InsertarAlumnos after insert
on alumno
for each row
insert into tb_alumno(alu_id,alu_pate,alu_mate,alu_nomb)
values(new.alu_id,new.alu_pate,new.alu_mate,new.alu_nomb);
```

Estoy intentando hace update con esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ModificarAlumnos
AFTER UPDATE
ON  alumno FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE tb_alumno
BEGIN
SET 
alu_id = new.alu_id,
alu_carn = new.alu_carn,
per_pate = new.per_pate, 
per_mate = new.per_mate, 
per_nomb = new.per_nomb
END;
```

y sale error, dice "Trigger in wrong schema". o no se si la sintaxis esta bien.
tambien me podrian ayudar con delete.

Espero su sugerencia y ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una especie de sincronización que actualice el registro de la otra tabla, tendrías que hacer algo así: `CREATE TRIGGER ModificarAlumnos
AFTER UPDATE
ON  alumno FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_alumno
 SET 
alu_id = new.alu_id,
alu_carn = new.alu_carn,
per_pate = new.per_pate, 
per_mate = new.per_mate, 
per_nomb = new.per_nomb WHERE alu_id = new.alu_id
END;`  quizá no haga falta ni tampoco convenga actualizar la columna `alu_id` sobre todo si es autoincremental.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu llave primaria es: alu_id  y que las dos tablas tienen la misma estructura.

1. El update, debe de estar dentro del BEGIN y el END
2. Solo será una sentencia por lo que no necesitas el BEGIN y el END
3. Te faltaba el WHERE de lo contrario te actualizara todos los
   registros

y te quedara algo asi:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ModificarAlumnos AFTER UPDATE ON alumno FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE tb_alumno 
SET alu_id = new.alu_id,
alu_carn = new.alu_carn,
per_pate = new.per_pate,
per_mate = new.per_mate,
per_nomb = new.per_nomb 
WHERE
    alu_id = new.alu_id;
```

y para el delete

```
CREATE TRIGGER EliminarAlumnos AFTER DELETE ON alumno FOR EACH ROW
DELETE 
FROM
    tb_alumno 
WHERE
    alu_id = OLD.alu_id;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Manuel.

Comment: Ya lo probaste? te funciono?